# Stream video From iPhone Or Android to RTMP

Tags: iphone, android, stream, red5, rtmp

is there any way to Stream video From iPhone Or Android to RTMP Server using Red5?? 
i searched over internet and there is only 2 application that mange to do this successfully
(UStream , Qik)
the problem they closed source So if anyone could help me find some code snippets that make this possible ??

Answer (score 2):

There is some Red5 RTMP library adaptation for android available:

http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/

http://code.google.com/p/android-recorder/

I'm working on video/audio live stream publishing from Android to Red5 server right now.

Comment: Hi miceuz,
I got the same task as yours to publish live stream from  android phone to Red5 server. I appreciate if you can help me out in this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a regular Adobe Air application and produce builds for both iOS and Android.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices.html

Comment: Be aware that codecs are limited on the devices, for instance you cannot use h.264 on android in air.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use RTMP, you will need an RTMP library that works in Objective-C for iOS and I don't know of one off the top of my head. For Android, there are many options since you can write your application in Java or C. If you want to start with the lightest weight java client that I am aware of, look into flazr at http://flazr.com/

Comment: You can also no use Flash or Air to develop a publisher for Android or iOS to Red5. I have a free Air app on the market here:  https://market.android.com/details?id=air.Broadcaster